# How to enforce that a type implements a trait at compile time?

Tags: macros, rust

I want to write a macro like this:

```
macro_rules! a {
    ( $n:ident, $t:ty ) => {
         struct $n {
             x: $t
         }
    }
}
```

But `$t` should implement `Add`, `Sub` and `Mul` traits. How can I check it at compile-time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, solve the problem without macros. One solution is to create undocumented private functions that will fail compilation if your conditions aren't met:

```rust
struct MyType {
    age: i32,
    name: String,
}

const _: () = {
    fn assert_send<T: Send>() {}
    fn assert_sync<T: Sync>() {}

    // RFC 2056
    fn assert_all() {
        assert_send::<MyType>();
        assert_sync::<MyType>();
    }
};
```

Then, modify the simple solution to use macros:

```rust
macro_rules! example {
    ($name:ident, $field:ty) => {
        struct $name {
            x: $field,
        }

        const _: () = {
            fn assert_add<T: std::ops::Add<$field, Output = $field>>() {}
            fn assert_mul<T: std::ops::Mul<$field, Output = $field>>() {}

            // RFC 2056
            fn assert_all() {
                assert_add::<$field>();
                assert_mul::<$field>();
            }
        };
    };
}

example!(Moo, u8);
example!(Woof, bool);
```

In both cases, we create a dummy `const` value to scope the functions and their calls, avoiding name clashes.

I would then trust in the optimizer to remove the code at compile time, so I wouldn't expect any additional bloat.

**Major thanks** to [Chris Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764797/how-to-enforce-that-a-macro-ty-argument-implements-a-trait-at-compile-time/32765782?noredirect=1#comment53385533_32765782) for providing a better version of this that supports non-object-safe traits.

It's worth highlighting [RFC 2056](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2056-allow-trivial-where-clause-constraints.md) which will allow for "trivial" constraints in where clauses. Once implemented, clauses like this would be accepted:

```rust
impl Foo for Bar
where 
    i32: Iterator,
{}
```

This exact behavior has changed multiple times during Rust's history and RFC 2056 pins it down. To keep the behavior we want in this case, we need to call the assertion functions from another function which has no constraints (and thus must always be true).

Comment: I’d go for `fn _assert_add() where Self: Add<Self, Output = Self> { } fn _verify_assertions() { Self::_assert_add() }`, myself. Slightly cleaner error messages, in my opinion, and (more importantly) more general as it doesn’t require the trait to be object-safe.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan wouldn't `Self` be the type being created, instead of the type of the field?

Comment: Oh yeah, I wasn’t reading it all fully. But that’s no problem—`where $t: Add<$t, Output = $t>` works just as well. The `where` clause can contain stuff for *any* type, not just stuff related to `Self` or generics.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan *The `where` clause can contain stuff for any type* — [mind. blown.](http://www3.pictures.zimbio.com/mp/mA5SbP1W53Ex.gif) Also, a function that starts with an underscore doesn't trigger the unused function lint. That makes sense, but still was surprising!

Comment: You could also merge the assertion methods with `where $t: Add + Mul` and suchlike, leaving you with just two methods. Entirely up to you.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan yeah, I was trying to decide which gave a better error message and thought that having the redundancy of the method name wasn't terrible. If the calling function wasn't needed, I'd definitely go for combining them.

Comment: Shepmaster, @ChrisMorgan, thank you for answer! It works very fine, and optimizer do its work really well.