# Is it possible to check if a field implements a trait with custom derive?

Tags: rust

```
struct Foo;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bar {
    f: Foo,
}

fn main() {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0638677ecd6bd61eb488fb330d4bff96&version=stable&backtrace=0)

This results in

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
 --> <anon>:5:5
  |
5 |     f: Foo,
  |     ^^^^^^ the trait `std::clone::Clone` is not implemented for `Foo`
  |
  = note: required by `std::clone::Clone::clone`
```

It is only possible to derive `Clone` if all the types of the fields implement clone. I would like to do the same thing.

[`Field`](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15/syn/struct.Field.html) does not seem to expose which traits it implements. How would I check if a [`Type`](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15/syn/enum.Type.html) implements a specific trait? Is this currently not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [expanded version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28580386/155423) of your code:

```
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#![no_std]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::v1::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std as std;
struct Foo;

struct Bar {
    f: Foo,
}
#[automatically_derived]
#[allow(unused_qualifications)]
impl ::std::clone::Clone for Bar {
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> Bar {
        match *self {
            Bar { f: ref __self_0_0 } => Bar { f: ::std::clone::Clone::clone(&(*__self_0_0)) },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

All it does is call a function that has a trait bound, passing in the arguments. This is useful because `clone` needs to be called recursively anyway. This gets you the check "for free".

If you don't need to call the trait in question, you can still do something similar to [enforce that an argument implements a trait at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32764797/155423). `Eq` does this by implementing a [hidden function on the trait](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.16.0/src/libcore/cmp.rs#L168). You could also generate one-off functions that express your trait bound.