# How does tokio::net::TcpStream implement tokio::prelude::Stream?

Tags: rust, traits, rust-tokio

In the [tokio.rs](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/echo/) docs we see the following snippet

```
// split the socket stream into readable and writable parts
let (reader, writer) = socket.split();
// copy bytes from the reader into the writer
let amount = io::copy(reader, writer);
```

I am assuming that `split` is indeed [`Stream::split`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/prelude/stream/trait.Stream.html), but I can't figure out how this trait applies to [`TcpStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html) given that the stream page doesn't mention `TcpStream` and vice versa.

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? Almost all traits are implemented for a type in the same way: `impl Trait for Type { ... }`. Sometimes that code is generated by a macro or whatever, but it's ultimately the same.

Comment: [The documentation shows](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-AsyncRead) what traits are implemented for a type and what methods they provide.

Comment: You can test if a type implements a trait: [How to enforce that a type implements a trait at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32764797/155423)

Comment: Perhaps my edits will help you understand what I am asking. I know how traits are defined. My question is that given that there isn't an obvious like between the two how do I establish that link? Is it some chain of blanket implementations? I have no idea.

Comment: When I linked to [the documentation for `TcpStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-AsyncRead), did you search on the page for the method `split`?

Comment: Well color me embarrassed. I swear I spent an age reading that + ctrl-f split. Shame!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tokio::net::TcpStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html) implements [`AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-AsyncRead).

One of the provided methods from `AsyncRead` is [`split()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.20/tokio/prelude/trait.AsyncRead.html#method.split):

```
fn split(self) -> (ReadHalf<Self>, WriteHalf<Self>)
where
    Self: AsyncWrite,
```

So in this case it isn't `Stream::split` as your question suggested because as per your observation `tokio::net::TcpStream` isn't an implementor of `Stream`.

Comment: It would probably be good if you explicitly laid out the exact steps you took to figure this so OP can apply the logic for other tasks.