# Where is the split() method of tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream implemented?

Tags: websocket, rust, rust-tokio

Where does [`tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream`](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/blob/6bda35bf531d5da224d55d48f0b052c8d2208389/src/lib.rs#L176) implement the `split()` function as used in [one of their examples](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/blob/6bda35bf531d5da224d55d48f0b052c8d2208389/examples/client.rs#L32)?

The following is a snippet of the example:

```
let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(url).await.expect("Failed to connect");

let (write, read) = ws_stream.split();
```

Someone else had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349398/how-does-tokionettcpstream-implement-tokiopreludestream) finding `split()` in `tokio::net::TcpStream` and the answer was that `TcpStream` implements `AsyncRead`. In the case of `WebSocketStream` I cannot see any `impl AsyncRead for WebSocketStream` code.

My broader question is what knowledge am I missing that stops me from finding methods such as `split()` and their implementations of a struct such as `WebSocketStream` in [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/) or in the source code?

Comment: [`StreamExt::split`](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.15/futures_util/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.split).  I found this by expanding all on the docs page for [`tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-tungstenite/0.14.0/tokio_tungstenite/struct.WebSocketStream.html) and then searching the page for "split"—but this won't work if the implementation is in a different package, as it won't appear in the struct's documentation.

Comment: Hi @eggyal thanks for the tip. It helped me realise that I misunderstood what blanket implementations are. `split()` is implemented by `Stream::split` which is a blanket implementation for `Stream`. Seeing as `WebSocketStream` implements `Stream` then it can use all the methods of `StreamExt`. Is this correct?

Comment: `WebSocketStream` implements `Stream`.  There is a blanket implementation of [`StreamExt` for all types that implement `Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#impl-StreamExt).  `StreamExt` has a `split` method.  It happens that this implementation just uses the default body for `split` that is (and indeed all methods that are) provided in the trait definition.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'll write it up as the answer unless you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept I was missing was that of *blanket implementations* where traits in modules that know nothing about the code in my module can add functionality to my structs. This is so long as the trait bounds of the external code fit my code.

In this situation `WebSocketStream` implements `Stream`. There is a trait `StreamExt` in the futures crate that knows nothing about `WebSocketStream` but is a blanket implementation for `Stream`. It provides the functionality of `split()` to `Stream` and as `WebSocketStream` implements `Stream` it also gets that functionality.