# Can I create a compile error to check if a trait has another trait as a supertrait?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm creating a macro that parses a user-generated trait and creates helper functions for it. I have type restrictions on some of the arguments used, so I've been following the [example in the quote crate](https://docs.rs/quote/1.0.7/quote/macro.quote_spanned.html#example) to generate some code that'll throw a compilation error if a trait isn't implemented. It's not perfect but it gets the job done:

```rust
struct _AssertSync where #ty: Sync;
```

I'd also like to be able to check if the trait has `Hash` as a supertrait. If I follow the same pattern, I get an error:

```
struct _AssertHash where dyn #tr: Hash;
```

A complete example:

```rust
use std::hash::Hash;

trait BadBoi {}
trait GoodBoi: Hash {}

struct _AssertHash
where
    dyn GoodBoi: Hash;
```

```
error[E0038]: the trait `GoodBoi` cannot be made into an object
   --> src/lib.rs:6:39
    |
4   | trait GoodBoi: Hash {}
    |       ------- this trait cannot be made into an object...
5   | 
6   | struct _AssertHash where dyn GoodBoi: Hash;
    |                                       ^^^^ the trait `GoodBoi` cannot be made into an object
    |
    = help: consider moving `hash` to another trait
```

Is there any way for me to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check a supertrait-relationship by using two functions, for example:

```rust
fn _assert_hash_supertrait<T: $tr>() {
    fn requires_hash<T: Hash>() {}
    let _ = requires_hash::<T>;
}
```

This only compiles if the bound `T: $tr` implies `T: Hash`. And the only way that's the case if `Hash` is a super-trait of `$tr`. Also see [this helpful Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764797/how-to-enforce-that-a-type-implements-a-trait-at-compile-time).

Full example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6cee1c858803d0993c30ccde332abf81)):

```rust
trait BadBoi {}
trait GoodBoi: Hash {}

macro_rules! foo {
    ($tr:ident) => {
        fn _assert_hash_supertrait<T: $tr>() {
            fn requires_hash<T: Hash>() {}
            let _ = requires_hash::<T>;
        }
    }
}

//foo!(GoodBoi);
foo!(BadBoi);
```

Of course in this solution, calling `foo!` twice errors because `assert_hash_supertrait` is defined twice, but solving that is not part of this question.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I added a little tweak: adding `use _DummyName as $tr`, and then `fn _assert_hash_supertrait<$tr: _DummyName>`. That way the error message that gets shown to the user has the correct identifier attached (there's no way to use custom error messages, right?!)

Comment: @Alastair Custom error messages: not in this case. This kind of super-trait error always has  the same message. You can emit custom messages in some cases (e.g. via [`compile_error!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.compile_error.html)), but that won't help you here.